# How to I change the URL in SideNav in Discussion Board

Tags: url, discussion-board

I would like to find out if there is a way to change the URL of the Side Navi/Bar items? For example i want to change the link for Categories to another Site Page called Navigation Tiles

When i go into Look and Feel, Navigation does not help

much appreciated[image]

Comment: Look https://sharepointotoole.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/global-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: thanks! i have managed to solve this by editing this as well

Comment: well, published the answer to your question, you can make a note that the answer is given.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit these links in **Site Actions** > **Site Settings** > **Top link Bar**. 
Also, you can no longer rename the *Home Page* link from this menu (it disappears when you put it into edit mode). To change it you’ll have to go to **Site Actions** > **Site Settings** > *Title*, *Description* and *Icon*. Once you change the *Title* of the site here it will automatically take effect in the top navigation.
Read more [here](https://sharepointotoole.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/global-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013/).